# WAS hung threads

Tags: websphere

> [11/18/08 10:13:08:772 GMT+05:30] 690f5641 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0606W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2162" (690f5641) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 1,032,152 milliseconds.  There are 21 threads in total in the server that still may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:775 GMT+05:30] 73f09641 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0606W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2149" (73f09641) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 1,139,386 milliseconds.  There are 17 threads in total in the server that still may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:775 GMT+05:30] 696c9641 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0606W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2144" (696c9641) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 1,139,374 milliseconds.  There are 18 threads in total in the server that still may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:828 GMT+05:30] 4e961648 SystemOut     O actionIDs.size() = 0
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:774 GMT+05:30] 690b5641 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0606W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2163" (690b5641) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 993,865 milliseconds.  There are 20 threads in total in the server that still may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:840 GMT+05:30] 4e961648 SystemOut     O ENTERING TO EMPTY THEME  DEFAULT .JSP 
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:775 GMT+05:30]  fd71646 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0606W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2155" (fd71646) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 1,139,386 milliseconds.  There are 19 threads in total in the server that still may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:13:08:951 GMT+05:30] 4e961648 WebGroup      I SRVE0180I: [WebSphere Portal Server] [/wps] [Servlet.LOG]: /screens/html/Login.jsp: init
>   [11/18/08 10:13:09:100 GMT+05:30] 4e961648 SystemOut     O EXITING FROM CORPORATE  DEFAULT .JSP 
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:445 GMT+05:30] 7f025647 TimeoutManage I WTRN0006W: Transaction 57415344:000000000000302d00000003abdd0ab33759ecaaaf88a04568d6b035df3281225765625370686572655f506f7274616c[] has timed out after 120 seconds.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:444 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2178" (40535641) has been active for 833,039 milliseconds and may be hung.  There are 18 threads in total in the server that may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:479 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2192" (72769641) has been active for 833,040 milliseconds and may be hung.  There are 19 threads in total in the server that may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:484 GMT+05:30] 7f025647 TimeoutManage I WTRN0006W: Transaction 57415344:000000000000303000000003abdd0ab33759ecaaaf88a04568d6b035df3281225765625370686572655f506f7274616c[] has timed out after 120 seconds.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:485 GMT+05:30] 7f025647 TimeoutManage I WTRN0006W: Transaction 57415344:000000000000303200000003abdd0ab33759ecaaaf88a04568d6b035df3281225765625370686572655f506f7274616c[] has timed out after 120 seconds.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:485 GMT+05:30] 238e564c TimeoutManage I WTRN0006W: Transaction 57415344:000000000000303100000003abdd0ab33759ecaaaf88a04568d6b035df3281225765625370686572655f506f7274616c[] has timed out after 120 seconds.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:495 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2195" (724a9641) has been active for 833,038 milliseconds and may be hung.  There are 20 threads in total in the server that may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:498 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2153" (fdf1646) has been active for 833,070 milliseconds and may be hung.  There are 21 threads in total in the server that may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:504 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2193" (72729641) has been active for 833,039 milliseconds and may be hung.  There are 22 threads in total in the server that may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:514 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Servlet.Engine.Transports : 2196" (72469641) has been active for 833,039 milliseconds and may be hung.  There are 23 threads in total in the server that may be hung.
>   [11/18/08 10:14:58:517 GMT+05:30] 7f325647 ThreadMonitor W WSVR0605W: Thread "Ser...

MY wAS server is very slow and hangs..and i have to reboot.

Anyone can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Its often an application hanging (waitin for an external resource etc). Try shutting down the app that was changed last, wait and see if the threads are dying eventually.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question: [WAS threads are getting hung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843157/was-threads-are-getting-hung)

The main idea is to avoid hung threads. Force a thread dump and then analyze why a certain thread is hung. Typical reasons for hanging threads are unanswered connection attempts, infinte loops or simply a part of your code that actually runs very long (like poorly written watchdogs or something like that).